# 4D contour plots in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have 4D data X,Y,Z plus a field. I would like to do a 4d plot of the field restricted to a sphere. I already use `splot w pm3d` to have the color bar on the sphere indexed by my field, but I think it would be more readable if I could add 3d contour lines.

I would like something like last example of "function plot" (protein orientation) at http://www.originlab.com/index.aspx?go=Products/Origin/Graphing

Is it even possible in gnuplot ? If so, how to do it ?

Comment: Gnuplot cannot do this out-of-the-box. In any case you'll need to prepare your data with a separate program before plotting it. But I can't tell you how...

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot cannot generate 4d contour plots.

But if I understand correctly, you have a special case, you do not really have 4d data. The z coordinate depends on x and y such that the point is on a sphere. Maybe this can be used to get the contours.

I assume the datafile contains datapoints for the complete sphere, arranged circle by circle from bottom to top of the sphere, each circle in a separate block.

I have tried this:

- Separate the points on the upper half from points of the lower half of the sphere, we need this separation for the sign of z.
- Plot the contours of the two halfs in two datafiles contour_l.dat and contour_u.dat. This will only plot the x and y coordinates.
- Merge the original datafile and the two contour datafiles into one plot. Pythagoras could help reconstructing the z coordinates for the contour datafiles.

This is the script:

```
set pm3d depthorder interpolate 5,5
set hidden3d front

unset surface
set contour surface

set zrange [0:1.1]
set table "contour_u.dat"
splot "sh.dat" using 1:2:4 w l
unset table

set zrange [-1.1:0]
set table "contour_l.dat"
splot "sh.dat" using 1:2:4 w l
unset table

set surface
unset contour

set xrange [-1.1:1.1]
set yrange [-1.1:1.1]
set zrange [-1.1:1.1]
set xyplane relative 0.0

set terminal pngcairo size 640,640
set output "c.png"

unset key

splot "sh.dat" using 1:2:3:4 w pm3d, \
      "contour_u.dat" using 1:2:( sqrt(1.0-($1*$1+$2*$2))):3 w l lc rgb "black",\
      "contour_l.dat" using 1:2:(-sqrt(1.0-($1*$1+$2*$2))):3 w l lc rgb "black"
```

You did not post data, so I have taken one of the spherical harmonics. With Gnuplot 4.6, I get the following result:

[image: sphere with pm3d and contour lines]

As you can see, it is still not perfect. The contour at x=0 should be investigated, and if I remove the `"sh.dat" w pm3d` line, the image gets very strange.

But at least this approach might be a starting point, one could try to manually play with the contour line datafiles.